# MySQL Query to search in between tow timestamp columns for a range of tow posted dates records

Tags: mysql

Please help me with this,

Am posting 2 dates to search for vehicles that went for maintenance and left in a certain date, then these results are split in time ranges.
My table looks like this:

```
Ticket          VEhicle         Type            Model           Center          Depart          DateIn                      DateOut
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
JBN-115         D113            MOTO BIKE       YBR125          254             403             2017-01-16 16:38:00         2017-01-25 08:54:00
JBN-122         S001            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 08:39:00         2017-01-17 09:39:00
JBN-123         C003            MOTO BIKE       MAX100R         254             403             2017-01-16 09:50:00         2017-01-17 09:41:00
JBN-124         D313            MOTO BIKE       YBR125          254             403             2017-01-16 16:38:00         2017-01-25 08:54:00
JBN-125         S002            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 12:39:00         2017-01-18 14:39:00
JBN-126         C053            MOTO BIKE       MAX100R         254             403             2017-01-16 08:41:00         2017-01-31 09:41:00
JBN-127         D133            MOTO BIKE       YBR125          254             403             2017-01-18 15:38:00         2017-01-25 08:54:00
JBN-128         S008            MOTO BIKE       TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 13:13:00         2017-01-20 09:24:00
JBN-129         C043            MOTO BIKE       MAX100R         254             403             2017-01-18 08:41:00         2017-01-31 09:41:00
JBN-122         S012            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 08:50:00         2017-01-17 19:39:00
JBN-122         S062            MOTO BIKE       YBR125          254             410             2017-01-17 14:50:00
```

so if a vehicle went for maintenance in the posted date ranges and it still has not letf the maintenance place, it will show in the results even if the date Out is past the posted date.
or if the date out is blank, it will still show because it has not yet left the place.

so am running a query to get records between 2017-01-17 and 2017-01-18

the query should look for this vehicles since thy fall in the criteria:

```
Ticket          VEhicle         Type            Model           Center          Depart          DateIn                      DateOut
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
JBN-122         S001            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 08:39:00         2017-01-17 09:39:00
JBN-122         S012            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 08:50:00         2017-01-17 19:39:00
JBN-125         S002            CAR             TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 12:39:00         2017-01-18 14:39:00
JBN-128         S008            MOTO BIKE       TYT HILUX       254             410             2017-01-17 13:13:00         2017-01-20 14:24:00
JBN-122         S062            MOTO BIKE       YBR125          254             410             2017-01-17 14:50:00
```

then i am hopping to see the output of the query like this:

```
Type        8am     10am    12pm    2pm     4pm
_________________________________________________
CAR         2       1       2       2       2
MOTO BIKE   0       0       1       2       2
```

i have tried this:

```
select c.vtype, 
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where (DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-17 00:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-18 10:00') AND costCente = '254' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Eight,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where (DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-17 10:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-18 12:00') AND  costCente = '254' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Ten,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where (DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-17 12:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-18 14:00') AND  costCente = '254' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Twelve,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where (DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-17 14:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-18 16:00') AND  costCente = '254' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Tow,
   ( select COUNT(vtype) from Availability where (DATE_FORMAT(DateIn, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-17 16:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOut, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < '2017-01-18 19:00') AND  costCente = '254' AND vtype =c.vtype ) as Four
   from Availability c where costCente = '254' GROUP BY vtype ORDER BY vtype DESC
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried the above edit and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what condition for your time range is, example 8am: DateIn < '2017-01-17 00:00' and DateOut < '2017-01-18 10:00', there is no connection between 8am and this. 
So I suppose 8am is range time for counting how many vehicles which are still at maintenance between 0 am to 8 am

```
SET         @FromTime   = '2017-01-17 00:00:00',
            @ToTime     = '2017-01-18 23:59:59';

SELECT      Type,
            sum(if(DateIn between @FromTime and @FromTime+interval 8 hour,1,0)) as `8am`,
            sum(if(DateIn between @FromTime +interval 8 hour and @FromTime+interval 10 hour,1,0)) as `10am`,
            sum(if(DateIn between @FromTime +interval 10 hour and @FromTime+interval 12 hour,1,0)) as `12am`,
            sum(if(DateIn between @FromTime +interval 12 hour and @FromTime+interval 14 hour,1,0)) as `2pm`,
            sum(if(DateIn between @FromTime +interval 14 hour and @FromTime+interval 16 hour,1,0)) as `4pm`

FROM        Availability

WHERE       costCente = '254'
            AND DateIn >= @FromTime AND if(DateOut = '',DateIn,DateOut) <= @ToTime

GROUP BY    1 
ORDER BY    1 DESC;
```

You can modify the condition in if to suit your case.

Comment: It's not adding the future dates in the rest of the hours. Like a date is blank or past the date range posted, it should have shown the vehicle to be in the place for the whole date. (All time intervals)

Comment: I believe it is in my WHERE condition :)
if(DateOut = '',DateIn,DateOut) <= @ToTime